# What is the source of this hadith about Abu Hurairah (RA)?

Tags: hadith, source-identification, authenticity

I was recently answering a question about Abu Hurairah (RA), and I found the following hadith on sunnahonline.com:

> Zayd bin Thabit reported, “Abu Huraira, another friend, and I were praying in the masjid. The Prophet came and sat down beside us. We stopped talking. But the Prophet told us to continue. So my friend and I prayed. The Prophet said ‘Ameen’.
>
> Then Abu Huraira prayed. He asked for what we asked. But he also asked for knowledge that would not be forgotten. The Prophet again said ‘Ameen’.
>
> Then we asked for knowledge that would not be forgotten, too. But the Prophet said that the Daws youth asked first. ([Sunnah Online](http://sunnahonline.com/library/history-of-islam/306-abu-hurayrah))

But, I could not find the original source of this narration. I don't think it is from either Bukhari or Muslim. So, what is the original source of this narration and how authentic is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version I found includes an introduction which is missing here in your quote and it can be found in al-Hakim from Naishapur's al-Mustadrak, ([here](https://www.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?idfrom=6042&idto=6042&bk_no=74&ID=2631) in Arabic) the person who reported it was Muhammad ibn Qais ibn Makhramah محمد بن قيس بن مخرمة the main difference in this report is that it starts by:

> "Zayd ibn Tahbet was asked by a man about something (a knowledge), so he told (or recommended) him to ask abu Hurairah about it and started reporting: "While me, abu Hurairah and so and so where in the mosque ..."".

Here the Arabic text as is in al-Mustadrak:

> 6214 - حدثنا أبو عبد الله محمد بن عبد الله الأصبهاني ، ثنا الحسين بن  حفص ، ثنا حماد بن شعيب ، عن إسماعيل بن أمية ، أن محمد بن قيس بن مخرمة ، حدثه ، أن رجلا جاء زيد بن ثابت فسأله عن شيء ، فقال له زيد : عليك بأبي هريرة ، **فإنه بينا أنا وأبو هريرة وفلان في المسجد ذات يوم ندعو الله تعالى ، ونذكر ربنا خرج علينا رسول الله صلى الله عليه وآله وسلم حتى جلس إلينا ، قال : فجلس وسكتنا ، فقال : " عودوا للذي كنتم فيه " . قال زيد : فدعوت أنا وصاحبي قبل أبي هريرة ، وجعل رسول الله صلى الله عليه وآله وسلم يؤمن على دعائنا ، قال : ثم دعا أبو هريرة فقال : اللهم إني أسألك مثل الذي سألك صاحباي هذان ، وأسألك علما لا ينسى ، فقال رسول الله صلى الله عليه وآله وسلم : " آمين " . فقلنا : يا رسول الله ، ونحن نسأل الله علما لا ينسى . فقال : " سبقكما بها الدوسي " .**

The bold part is that which was already translated in the given source. Al-Hakim qualified this hadith as sahih and not compiled by neither al-Bukhari nor Muslim.
Imam a-Dhahabi commented on this comment in his Talkhis al-Mustadrak تلخيص المستدرك Vol 5 (see [here](https://books.google.de/books?id=xhBGCwAAQBAJ&pg=PT64&lpg=PT64&dq=%D9%81%D8%A5%D9%86%D9%87%20%D8%A8%D9%8A%D9%86%D8%A7%20%D8%A3%D9%86%D8%A7%20%D9%88%D8%A3%D8%A8%D9%88%20%D9%87%D8%B1%D9%8A%D8%B1%D8%A9%20%D9%88%D9%81%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%86%20%D9%81%D9%8A%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%B3%D8%AC%D8%AF%20%D8%B0%D8%A7%D8%AA%20%D9%8A%D9%88%D9%85%20%D9%86%D8%AF%D8%B9%D9%88%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%84%D9%87%20%D8%AA%D8%B9%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%89%20%D8%8C%20%D9%88%D9%86%D8%B0%D9%83%D8%B1%20%D8%B1%D8%A8%D9%86%D8%A7%20%D8%AE%D8%B1%D8%AC%20%D8%B9%D9%84%D9%8A%D9%86%D8%A7%20%D8%B1%D8%B3%D9%88%D9%84%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%84%D9%87%20%D8%B5%D9%84%D9%89%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%84%D9%87%20%D8%B9%D9%84%D9%8A%D9%87%20%D9%88%D8%A2%D9%84%D9%87%20%D9%88%D8%B3%D9%84%D9%85%20%D8%AD%D8%AA%D9%89%20%D8%AC%D9%84%D8%B3%20%D8%A5%D9%84%D9%8A%D9%86%D8%A7%20%D8%8C%20%D9%82%D8%A7%D9%84%20:%20%D9%81%D8%AC%D9%84%D8%B3%20%D9%88%D8%B3%D9%83%D8%AA%D9%86%D8%A7%20%D8%8C%20%D9%81%D9%82%D8%A7%D9%84%20:%20%22%20%D8%B9%D9%88%D8%AF%D9%88%D8%A7%20%D9%84%D9%84%D8%B0%D9%8A%20%D9%83%D9%86%D8%AA%D9%85%20%D9%81%D9%8A%D9%87%20%22&source=bl&ots=6LeAq616UN&sig=ACfU3U2jgBc-xeD0ncXA5_RL1RBa6zNGiw&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiZ_r-XhtfgAhUIGuwKHdbqACoQ6AEwAnoECAYQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D9%81%D8%A5%D9%86%D9%87%20%D8%A8%D9%8A%D9%86%D8%A7%20%D8%A3%D9%86%D8%A7%20%D9%88%D8%A3%D8%A8%D9%88%20%D9%87%D8%B1%D9%8A%D8%B1%D8%A9%20%D9%88%D9%81%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%86%20%D9%81%D9%8A%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%B3%D8%AC%D8%AF%20%D8%B0%D8%A7%D8%AA%20%D9%8A%D9%88%D9%85%20%D9%86%D8%AF%D8%B9%D9%88%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%84%D9%87%20%D8%AA%D8%B9%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%89%20%D8%8C%20%D9%88%D9%86%D8%B0%D9%83%D8%B1%20%D8%B1%D8%A8%D9%86%D8%A7%20%D8%AE%D8%B1%D8%AC%20%D8%B9%D9%84%D9%8A%D9%86%D8%A7%20%D8%B1%D8%B3%D9%88%D9%84%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%84%D9%87%20%D8%B5%D9%84%D9%89%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%84%D9%87%20%D8%B9%D9%84%D9%8A%D9%87%20%D9%88%D8%A2%D9%84%D9%87%20%D9%88%D8%B3%D9%84%D9%85%20%D8%AD%D8%AA%D9%89%20%D8%AC%D9%84%D8%B3%20%D8%A5%D9%84%D9%8A%D9%86%D8%A7%20%D8%8C%20%D9%82%D8%A7%D9%84%20%3A%20%D9%81%D8%AC%D9%84%D8%B3%20%D9%88%D8%B3%D9%83%D8%AA%D9%86%D8%A7%20%D8%8C%20%D9%81%D9%82%D8%A7%D9%84%20%3A%20%22%20%D8%B9%D9%88%D8%AF%D9%88%D8%A7%20%D9%84%D9%84%D8%B0%D9%8A%20%D9%83%D9%86%D8%AA%D9%85%20%D9%81%D9%8A%D9%87%20%22&f=false) in Arabic) by the simple words:

> حماد بن شعيب ضعيف
>   Hammad ibn Sho'aib is da'if

Imam at-Tabarani compiled it in his al-Majma' al-Awsat (see [here](https://www.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?flag=1&bk_no=85&bookhad=1230) in Arabic) and added that according to him none reported this from Isma'ail ibn Umayyah (إسماعيل بن أمية) except with al-Fadl ibn al-'Ala' ( الفضل بن العلاء) and he doesn't know a different sanad from Zayd ibn Thabet this version was also quoted by an-Nasa-i in his as-Sunan al-Kubra as pointed at by @UmH in the comment, ibn Hajar also pointed at that in his al-Isabah.
But his sanad clearly differs from that of al-Hakim in these points, as al-Hakim has narrated the hadith via Hammad ibn Sho'aib instead if al-Fadl ibn al-'Ala'!

Al-Haythami quoted at-Tabaranis version also in his Majma' az-Zawa'id (see [here](https://www.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?flag=1&bk_no=87&bookhad=16129) in Arabic and later quoting other sources like al-Musnad with a hadith narration that is close in the meaning see [here](https://www.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?flag=1&bk_no=6&bookhad=20752) in Arabic) and commented that none has reporetd from Qais except with his son Muhammad and the rest of the narrators are trustworthy.

Comment: Also in [Sunan Nasa'i
 (Kubrah)](https://al-maktaba.org/book/33867/8115#p1) , [al-Isabah](https://al-maktaba.org/book/9767/3890#p8)